# in app purchase, production receipt validation now validating sandbox purchases?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Is it anyone else's experience that lately (Nov. 2011) the production URL for validating In App Purchase receipts now works to validate sandbox-generated receipts?

If this can be relied upon its a huge boon for me.  It means that the build I submit to Apple can be *exactly* the same as the build I test with (except for final code signing.)

I'm referring to https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt and https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed this too, and it is May 2012 so I guess this has been working for awhile.

Comment: Same here today validating a receipt from a content server. Nice surprise.

Answer (score 1):

This is no longer working as of 7/26/2012 (just found this post here, trying to figure out when it originally changed). You'll need to go back to the prod -> sandbox failover code, detailed in this tech note - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2259/_index.html

I'm guessing this is because of all the hacking of IAPs going on, and Apple now closing possible loopholes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want identical development and life behaviour (plus identical behaviour while your app is being reviewed): Verify the purchase first with the life server, and if it fails with the sandbox server.